# Junit Test case example for Sax Parsing code

Tags: java, junit, mockito, sax

I have written the Sax parser code in java. I have two classes one handler class which actually does the parsing and extends the Default handler class of Sax parser. The other class is the parser class which sets the property and features of sax parser, sets the handler, sets the exception class and class the parse method. I want to write the Junit test class for this method. Can anybody help me with the resource on how I should write the Junit test case for this?

I can share my code but I think I have explained it so if you could help me with the example on the Junit test case?

Comment: Please check my code looks very similar to the example in the link https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/sax-parser-read-xml-example/ and I would like to write unit test case for method parseXml() in UsersXmlParser class.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the testing of the contract of your library.
Basically SAX parse should allow parsing the XML with various flavors (managed by configurations). So the template of the test can be:

```
public class ParserTest {

    @Test
    public void testParse() {
        // given:
        SaxParser underTest = createParser(); // create with configurations

        // when:
        actualResult = underTest.parseXml(<XML_FILE_GOES_HERE>);

        // then:
        assertThat(actualResult, matchesContent());
     } 
}
```

You can prepare a series of tests like this to cover  various cases that the sax parser should deal with (hierarchical tags, attributes, and so forth).

You can treat 2 classes (the parser and the configuration) as one component and write a unit test that will cover them both. So no need for mockito in this case (that you’ve specified in the question’s tags).

In addition you can treat a configuration as a separated component and check that it produces the correct configuration, again test for behavioral contract.

Regarding the assertions of XML. You might find useful [xml unit library](https://www.baeldung.com/xmlunit2)

Answer (score 0):

use assertXXX methods to verify the values in the output object, use @Expected for exception scenarios.

For the example link you have mentioned here , we can check size of arraylist in assertEquals as well as assertTrue for list shouldnt be empty.In addition to this we can check assertEquals for the contents in the elements in the arrayList.Hope that suffices !!